# What caused this weird geometry when I applied the mirror modifier?

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution, mirror-modifier

Just applied mirror modifier and this happens, Do I have to resculpt the entire thing again?

[image]

PS: Does anything work like it is supposed to in 3.0?

Just googled how to use mesh symmetrize, and this is what it does

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .blend to https://pasteall.org/blend/ ? Thanks.

Comment: @Benus here https://pasteall.org/blend/12d50fc76c1e43c08ab730cb7586acea

Comment: I don't know what happened but if you do a Mesh > Symmetrize (in Edit mode) on X to -X, it will fix the problem

Comment: It looks to me like you had a model with multi-res -> mirror, and you applied the mirror without applying the multi-res.  Is that correct?  Applying the second modifier is like moving it to the top of the stack.  You need to apply all modifiers in order to get the same final output.

Comment: As an answer to your question: "Does anything work like it is supposed to in 3.0?", as @Nathan pointed out it looks like you applied the modifiers not in the correct order - this might cause problems and not only in 3.0 but previous versions as well. You even get a warning from Blender in the status bar: "_Applied modifier was not first, result may not be as expected._" Which means it works as it is supposed to, although the result might not be what you expected - but Blender told you so.

Answer (score 2):

1. go in front view (1), check [image]

[image]

now select these vertices:

[image]

then delete.

Then add a mirror modifier again:

[image]

then it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you kept the bad part  ^^

Comment: i thought this was what he wants ....‍♂️

Comment: oh ok maybe. But Mesh > Symmetrize is even faster than the Mirror modifier

Comment: @moonboots how do you use mesh symmetrize?

Comment: In Edit mode, select all, go to the header menu > Mesh > Symmetrize, then in the Operator box (bottom left) choose the axis (X to -X for example)

Comment: yes, but the mirror modifier is non destructive!!!!!!! ^^

Comment: Since he applied the mirror modifier anyway, I guess he didn't care for non-destructivity. On the contrary, reading his posts I get the feeling he prefers destructivity over constructivity...